# scroll top according to url parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site that carries a particular parameter in the URL called "onsale". I would like the page to scroll to a certain div with a class called "bbbb" when the page loads IF the parameter "onsale" is in the URL. Here is my code so far:

```
var url = window.location.href;

if (url.search("onsale") >= 0) {
//found it, now do something
console.log("yep");

jQuery('html,body').animate({
scrollTop: jQuery(".bbbb").offset().top
});

//jQuery("body")jQuery('.four-column-sales-pod').scrollTop();


}
```

The scroll effect has two problems.

1. it is not scrolling the window so that the div "bbbb" is at the top of the page - it scrolls so that it overshoots the div by about half of the div length.
2. The more confusing issue is that sometimes it will scroll to the div at halfway and othertimes it will scroll to the div at halfway then scroll back to the top of the page. Have no idea what is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;

    if (url.search('onsale') != -1) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.bbbb').offset().top
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Still both issues are present :(

Comment: Can you send me the url of that page in question? It will be difficult to diagnose the problem without some more context.